# What does moment not parse my date? (dd MMM YY)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Moment is not parsing my date and I am stumped as to why?

```
moment('28 Jun 19', "dd MMM YY");
```

Comment: Try improving your question. Add what you tried and what are the results.

Comment: `moment(your_date).format(your_format)`

Answer (score 2):

[Format docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) says that `dd` is `Su Mo ... Fr Sa`, you need `DD`

```js
let date = moment('28 Jun 19', "DD MMM YY");
console.log(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
moment(your-date).format('DD/MM/YYY')
```

Comment: As your answer can be the answer to the question, I encourage you to read the [answer] page to improve your answer.